# How can I use words in PHP date format?

Tags: php

I want to use PHP date to write something like:

```
Generated Fri, Aug 30, 2013 at 1:00pm
```

using:

```
echo "Generated ".date('D, M j, Y at g:ia');
```

However, I cannot use the "at" because that is swapped with 00am

Is there a way to include the word at in the date formation without using two date()?

Comment: `.date('D, M j, Y \a\t g:ia');`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can escape characters in the output like this:

```
echo "Generated ".date('D, M j, Y \a\t g:ia');
```

The following is taken from the PHP Date function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
<?php
// prints something like: Wednesday the 15th
echo date('l \t\h\e jS');
?>
```

Comment: not work with my code. would you please help    
$last_modified_date = new DateTime();
$last_modified_date->format("l \a\t H:ia");

Comment: echo  date("l \a\t H:ia"); also not worked I am using php 7.1.* version

Comment: For escaping "t" it seems single quotes are necessary date('l \a\t H:ia'), my hunch is to do with it being a special character (tab) although curiously with "n" you can use two backslashes with double quotes ie. "\\n"

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "Generated ".date('D, M j, Y \a\t g:ia');
```